# Restrict user to create an reference of a class

Tags: java

We restrict user to create objects of a class by declaring class as **abstract** or by using private constructor or any method
But my doubt is **How can prevent user to even create even an reference of a class**
For example:

```
 class emp
{
    int eno;
}
 class Test
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        emp e;//here User shud not be allowed to create an reference 

    }

}
```

Comment: Why at all would you like to do that? By the way, that's not creating an instance. You are declaring a reference of that class.

Comment: If the user can edit the class to access its private constructor, the user can edit *anything* in the class definition.

Comment: I'am not doing anything. This is just my doubt **To prevent user to create even reference of a class** just as we restrict on creation of objects of class..

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the class to be accessible from other packages you could declare it ommiting the `public` keyword.

So, instead of declaring it as

```
public class Test{
  //...
}
```

You could use:

```
class Test{
  //...
}
```

That way only classes inside the same package will have access to it. See [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more information.

**This will avoid other classes (outside the package) referencing `Test`, but it will not prevent `Test` from being instantiated within the same package.** If you want to prevent instantiation, create a private constructor as others have already said.

Answer (score 1):

> How can prevent user to even create an instance of a class

Don't know what will you do with that class but You can prevent user to NOT create an instane of your class by marking the constructor private.

Comment: I think OP is asking any way to not allow declaring any reference of the class. He knows about private constructor.

Comment: @RajendraJadi. `object` == `instance`.

Comment: The OP does not seem to understand the meaning of the word "instance" in common OOP language.

Answer (score 0):

make the constructor as private. refer the below code

```
 class emp
{
    int eno;

    private emp(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making private constructor won't solve the problem.

You can provide a `public` `static` method say `getInstance()` and then from there you can return the instance of the class like this.

```
public class Emp{
    private Emp(){
    }
    /*Constructor private? No worries. 
      We can still create an instance using a public static method. 
      Just call Emp.getInstance().*/
    public static Emp getInstance(){
        return new Emp();
    }
}
```

You have to make the class as `abstract`

```
public abstract class Emp{
     //Method implementations 
}
```

This won't allow to crate instances of class using it's own constructor. However, we can create instances of this class using the derived class constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do something like that?
First let see When and how the class instance is Created. 
- Normally ClassLoader loads and creates the class Instance. So Class Instance is created 
  once per ClassLoader hierarchy/per JVM.
  But User is Free to write their own ClassLoader load and create Class Objects. So again your
purpose is not fullfilled.

You can possibly only restrict user to use the class instance.
1. Private Inner/Nested Class. These classes will not be visible outside The Outer class.

There is one way by which you can actually restrict creation of class Instance 
** but its bad way **
 **Throw runtime exception in class static initializer **

Example

```
//Please don't try at home :)
private static class UnloadableClazz {
        static {
            if(true){
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }

        public static String data = "data-value";
    }
```